# Reducer not updating state with destructed property

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following action:

`{type: "SET_GROUP", group: 68, categories: Array(3), year: 64}`

In my reducer I have the following code:

```
    case "SET_GROUP":
        const { group } = action;

        const showStudent = !checkEmptyArray(action);
        return { ...state, group, showStudent };
```

However, `group` is never added to the state:

```
{year: 64, group: 0, student: 0, showStudent: true}
```

Any ideas?

Reducer:

```
export function setCredentials(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_YEAR":
            return {
                ...state,
                year: action.year,
                group: 0,
                student: 0
            };
        case "SET_STUDENT":
            return { ...state, student: action.student };
        case "SET_GROUP":
            const { group } = action;

            const showStudent = !checkEmptyArray(action);

            return { ...state, group, showStudent };
        case "CLEAR_CREDENTIALS":
            return initialState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

InitialState:

```
const initialState = {
    year: 0,
    group: 0,
    student: 0,
    showStudent: false
};
```

Comment: Can you show your initial state?

Comment: updated question

Comment: If you console log `group` inside your `case`, what does it print?

Comment: `Group` is not defined, so weird

Comment: are you saving/loading the reducer state anyhow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are not using any save/load middleware (which might be the cause, and in case, you can solve it by doing a `localStorage.clear()` command in the developer tools js console of your browser)
Just as a test on your code, try this:

```
case "SET_GROUP":
    const showStudent = !checkEmptyArray(action);
    return { 
        ...state, 
        group: action.group, 
        showStudent 
    };
```

And also check your `"SET_YEAR"` case, in which, it modifies as well `group` and `student` attributes. This practice, may lead you to a messy reducer implementation if it gets bigger ( as it really does a `"SET_YEAR_RESET_GROUP_RESET_STUDENT"` action )